# Change button size in Jquery Mobile with a specified class

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I am designing a Mobile Apps using Jquery Mobile,
I hope I can get the result like this,

[image]

But what I get is this:
[image]

I dont want to use .ui-btn in my css, I already define custom-btn.
Below is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-page {
    background : transparent url("loginPage.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat      fixed!important;
        -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
        -moz-background-size: cover !important;
        -o-background-size: cover !important;
        background-size: cover !important;
    }
    .ui-input-text {
    width: 350px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    font-size: 150% !important;
    margin-left: 700px !important;
    }

    .custom-btn {
    width: 305px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    background-color:red !important;
    color:white !important;
    border: red !important;
    font-size: 150% !important;
    margin-left: 700px !important;
    }

</style>   

<!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jq_mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

<!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="jq_mobile/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script src="jq_mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
           <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext">Home Icon</a>
    </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="background">
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <input type="text" name="login_id" id="txtLogin" placeholder="Login Id" width="30px">
                <input type="password" name="pin" id="txtPin" placeholder="Pin" width="30"> 
                <input type="button" class="custom-btn" id="btnLogin" value="LOGIN">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Anyone know how to make it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: r u looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/2av2ny1d/2/

Comment: Nope. I don't want the long button (full screen - width) , I want specified width button and the login button should be red color.

Comment: so look like this? http://jsfiddle.net/2av2ny1d/3/

Comment: Sorry, since your answer is in comment, I cannot vote it for you.

Comment: i will post it in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply some other color to the button, you have to overwrite the default properties in `.ui-btn` class. For your safety purpose you can add one parent div above the button and refer the parent with this button, so that it will not affect globally.

```
  <div class="test">
        <input type="button" class="custom-btn" id="btnLogin" value="LOGIN" />
  </div>

 .test .ui-btn{background-color:red !important; width:220px !important; color:#fff !important;}
 .test .ui-btn:hover{background-color:#ededed !important; color:#000 !important;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2av2ny1d/3/)